# ReactiveUI: Testing progress indicator visibility while ReactiveAsyncCommand executes

Tags: system.reactive, reactiveui

I have a ReactiveAsyncCommand that for the moment are just sleeping for a while:

```
public ReactiveAsyncCommand SignIn { get; private set; }

//from constructor:
SignIn = new ReactiveAsyncCommand(this.WhenAny(x => x.Username, x => x.Password,
                                                  (u, p) =>
                                                  !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(u.Value) &&
                                                  !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.Value)));

SignIn.RegisterAsyncAction(_ => Thread.Sleep(4000));
```

I want to show a progress indicator while the command executes, so I have made a property to bind its visibility against:

```
private ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> _Waiting; 
public bool Waiting
{
    get { return _Waiting.Value; }
}

//from constructor:
_Waiting = SignIn.ItemsInflight
                 .Select(x => x > 0)
                 .ToProperty(this, x => x.Waiting);
```

So, even though it seems to work in practice, I would love a unit test showing that Waiting allways will be true while the command executes, and only then.

I have read [this blogpost about the testscheduler](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2011/01/18/testing-your-viewmodels-using-time-travel-and-reactiveui/), but struggle to put it to use.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void flag_waiting_while_signing_in()
    {

        (new TestScheduler()).With(scheduler =>
            {
                var vm = new SignInViewModel {Username = "username", Password = "password"};

                vm.SignIn.Execute(null);

                Assert.IsTrue(vm.Waiting); 
            });
    }
```

This test fails (waiting is false). I have tried to add a calls to `scheduler.start()` and `scheduler.advanceBy( )` but that didn't make any difference.

Is my approach to testing this wrong?
If the approach is right, what else is wrong?

**Edit**
So I changed the `Thread.Sleep()` as suggested:

```
SignIn.RegisterAsyncAction(_ =>
            {
                Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(4000));
            });
```

And tried to control time by calling `scheduler.AdvanceBy(...)` before checking the `Waiting`-flag. Still no green, though.

Comment: You need to use RegisterAsyncObservable instead, and specify RxApp.DispatcherScheduler as the scheduler for Interval

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. First, by `RxApp.DispatcherScheduler`, do you mean `RxApp.DeferredScheduler`? Second, in the comment above DeferredScheduler, it says that this scheduler is used for work items that should run on the ui thread. Eventually, I want my signin command to do something more useful. It the idea that I use the deferredscheduler when unittesting and the taskpool scheduler for real work?
Anyway, the test goes green now, but by checking that the flag is reset after the 4 sec delay, it went red again. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, I meant DeferredScheduler, though you're right, it's more realistic to use TaskPoolScheduler (and you'll get the same result!)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that TestScheduler is falling over, is that you have a source of asynchrony that is outside TestScheduler's view - the `Thread.Sleep`. There's no way that it can control it, it will *always* take up 4 real seconds. Replace it with an `Observable.Interval` instead and it should work as you expect

```
[TestMethod]
public void flag_waiting_while_signing_in()
{

    (new TestScheduler()).With(scheduler =>
        {
            var vm = new SignInViewModel {Username = "username", Password = "password"};

            vm.SignIn.Execute(null);

            scheduler.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000));
            Assert.IsTrue(vm.Waiting); 

            // Move past the end
            scheduler.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000));
            Assert.IsFalse(vm.Waiting); 
        });
}
```

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but the test still fails. Updated the question a little.

Comment: As mentioned in my comment on the question, the last assertion fails.