# Unit testing ViewModel property bound to ReactiveCommand IsExecuting

Tags: c#, unit-testing, system.reactive

I'm new to ReactiveUI and am following the example set out [here](https://reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/), and unit testing as I go.

As expected, the sample code works perfectly, but my unit test which asserts that the `SpinnerVisibility` property changes as expected when the `IsExecuting` property of my `ReactiveCommand` changes, does not.

As per the sample, I have properties on my view model for a spinner visibility and a command to execute a search:

```
public Visibility SpinnerVisibility => _spinnerVisibility.Value;

public ReactiveCommand<string, List<FlickrPhoto>> ExecuteSearch { get; protected set; }
```

And in the view model constructor I set up the `ExecuteSearch` command and `SpinnerVisibility` is set to change when the command is executing:

```
public AppViewModel(IGetPhotos photosProvider)
{
    ExecuteSearch = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<string, List<FlickrPhoto>>(photosProvider.FromFlickr);

    this.WhenAnyValue(search => search.SearchTerm)
        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800), RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
        .Select(searchTerm => searchTerm?.Trim())
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .Where(searchTerm => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm))
        .InvokeCommand(ExecuteSearch);

    _spinnerVisibility = ExecuteSearch.IsExecuting
        .Select(state => state ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed)
        .ToProperty(this, model => model.SpinnerVisibility, Visibility.Hidden);
}
```

My initial attempt was to directly invoke the command:

```
[Test]
public void SpinnerVisibility_ShouldChangeWhenCommandIsExecuting()
{
    var photosProvider = A.Fake<IGetPhotos>();
    var fixture = new AppViewModel(photosProvider);

    fixture.ExecuteSearch.Execute().Subscribe(_ =>
    {
        fixture.SpinnerVisibility.Should().Be(Visibility.Visible);
    });

    fixture.SpinnerVisibility.Should().Be(Visibility.Collapsed);
}
```

This did result in the `state => state ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed` lambda being executed, but the subsequent assertion fails as for some reason `SpinnerVisibility` is still `Collapsed`.

My next attempt was to indirectly invoke the command by emulating a search using `TestScheduler`:

```
[Test]
public void SpinnerVisibility_ShouldChangeWhenCommandIsExecuting()
{
    new TestScheduler().With(scheduler =>
    {
        var photosProvider = A.Fake<IGetPhotos>();
        var fixture = new AppViewModel(photosProvider);

        A.CallTo(() => photosProvider.FromFlickr(A<string>.Ignored)).ReturnsLazily(
            () => new List<FlickrPhoto> { new FlickrPhoto { Description = "a thing", Title = "Thing", Url = "https://thing.com" } });

        fixture.SearchTerm = "foo";
        scheduler.AdvanceByMs(801); // search is throttled by 800ms
        fixture.SpinnerVisibility.Should().Be(Visibility.Visible);
    });
}
```

As before, the lambda executes, `state` is `true` but then instantly re-executes, with `state` back to `false`, presumably because, being mocked, `photosProvider.FromFlickr` would return instantly (unlike retrieving images from the API normally), which would then mean the command was no longer executing.

I then came across Paul Bett's response to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047124/reactiveui-testing-progress-indicator-visibility-while-reactiveasynccommand-exe), and added an `Observable.Interval` to my mock:

```
A.CallTo(() => photosProvider.FromFlickr(A<string>.Ignored)).ReturnsLazily(
                    () =>
                    {
                        Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), scheduler);
                        return new List<FlickrPhoto> {new FlickrPhoto {Description = "a thing", Title = "Thing", Url = "https://thing.com"}};
                    });
```

and the corresponding test changes:

```
scheduler.AdvanceByMs(501);
fixture.SpinnerVisibility.Should().Be(Visibility.Collapsed);
```

This had no effect.

Finally, I awaited the `Interval`:

```
A.CallTo(() => photosProvider.FromFlickr(A<string>.Ignored)).ReturnsLazily(async
                    () =>
                    {
                        await Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), scheduler);
                        return new List<FlickrPhoto> {new FlickrPhoto {Description = "a thing", Title = "Thing", Url = "https://thing.com"}};
                    });
```

This allowed the `fixture.SpinnerVisibility.Should().Be(Visibility.Visible)` assertion to pass, but now regardless how far I advance the scheduler, the mocked method never seems to return and so the subsequent assertion fails.

Is this approach using `TestScheduler` correct/advised? If so, what am I missing? If not, how should this type of behaviour be tested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you are trying to test two independent things in one test. Separating the logic into more focused tests will cause you fewer headaches in the future when refactoring. Consider the following instead:

1. `SearchTerm_InvokesExecuteSearchAfterThrottle`
2. `SpinnerVisibility_VisibleWhenExecuteSearchIsExecuting`

Now you have *unit* tests that are verifying each piece of functionality individually. If one fails, you'll know exactly which expectation is broken because there is only one. Now, onto the actual tests...

Based on your code, I assume you're using `NUnit`, `FakeItEasy`, and `Microsoft.Reactive.Testing`. The recommended strategy for testing observables is to use the `TestScheduler` and assert the final outcome of the observable.

Here is how I would implement them:

```
using FakeItEasy;
using Microsoft.Reactive.Testing;
using NUnit.Framework;
using ReactiveUI;
using ReactiveUI.Testing;
using System;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;

...

public sealed class AppViewModelTest : ReactiveTest
{
    [Test]
    public void SearchTerm_InvokesExecuteSearchAfterThrottle()
    {
        new TestScheduler().With(scheduler =>
        {
            var sut = new AppViewModel(A.Dummy<IGetPhotos>());

            scheduler.Schedule(() => sut.SearchTerm = "A");
            scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(200), () => sut.SearchTerm += "B");
            scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(300), () => sut.SearchTerm += "C");
            scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(400), () => sut.SearchTerm += "D");
            var results = scheduler.Start(
                () => sut.ExecuteSearch.IsExecuting,
                0, 100, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800).Ticks + 402);

            results.Messages.AssertEqual(
                OnNext(100, false),
                OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800).Ticks + 401, true)
            );
        });
    }

    [Test]
    public void SpinnerVisibility_VisibleWhenExecuteSearchIsExecuting()
    {
        new TestScheduler().With(scheduler =>
        {
            var sut = new AppViewModel(A.Dummy<IGetPhotos>());

            scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(300),
                () => sut.ExecuteSearch.Execute().Subscribe());
            var results = scheduler.Start(
                () => sut.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SpinnerVisibility));

            results.Messages.AssertEqual(
                OnNext(200, Visibility.Collapsed),
                OnNext(301, Visibility.Visible),
                OnNext(303, Visibility.Collapsed));
        });
    }
}
```

Notice there is no need to even fake/mock `IGetPhotos` because your tests aren't verifying anything based on the duration of the command. They just care about *when* it executes.

Some things can be difficult to wrap your head around at first, such as when a tick actually occurs, but it's very powerful once you get the hang of it. Some debate could be had about the usage of ReactiveUI in the tests (e.g. `IsExecuting`, `WhenAnyValue`), but I think it keeps things succinct. Plus, you're using ReactiveUI in your application anyway so if those things broke your test I'd consider that a good thing.

Comment: Thanks for this Taylor - I've not used `ReactiveTest` before, so there's something else to read up on. This approach makes a lot of sense - I can see my initial approach was misguided - sadly however, I can't get this working - I found I was still using the reactiveui v7.4 nuget package and updated to the latest 8.0.0-alpha0117 - however, now the With extension to TestScheduler is complaining. Knowing which packages are required is pretty confusing - can you confirm which versions are required please?

Comment: It's a bit of a sticky situation with ReactiveUI 7.4 since it uses the `Rx-Main` NuGet package, which no longer has a corresponding version of `Rx-Testing` on NuGet. If you're stuck on ReactiveUI 7.4, you'll probably have to use [this old QA version I found](https://staging.nuget.org/packages/Rx-Testing/). With ReactiveUI 8, you should just be able to reference the `ReactiveUI.Testing` (this contains the `With` extension method) and `Microsoft.Reactive.Testing` NuGet packages.

Comment: To clarify, `Rx-Main` is the previous version of `System.Reactive`. `Rx-Testing` is the previous version of `Microsoft.Reactive.Testing`. They renamed the packages some time ago, but it has caused me a lot of headache with ReactiveUI (as you can see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49679552/is-it-possible-to-retain-backward-compatibility-after-a-nuget-package-rename)).

Comment: Thanks - getting closer now, but it looks like `Scheduler.Schedule` now expects a `Func` not an `Action` and I have an ambiguous call on `System.ObservableExtensions.Subscribe<T>(System.IObservable<T>, System.Action<T>` - I will have a play a bit later when I get home from work. This is more painful than expected :D

Comment: No problem. The `Action` version is an extension method. I've added the appropriate `using` statements to my answer.

Comment: Ah - nice one, the Concurrency ns was the one I was missing, thanks! I just have some `Subscribe` ambiguity between `System.Reactive` and `System.Reactive.Core`, which sounds an awful lot like tomorrow's problem :) Thanks for taking the time to answer & follow up, appreciated.